# CSS: Repeat image from specified position within image to another specified position

Tags: css, image, position, repeat

I have an image with the dimensions 36px (height) and 32px (width). I'm accessing the first and last 5 pixels with

```
background-position: 0 0;
background-position: -26px 0px;
```

These are put into two different divs with a width of 5px. Altogether I have three divs (left, middle, right)

I now want to use the middle part of the image to repeat itself with a width of 280px. However, I only want to access the image region in between 6px - 26px.

IMAGE:

```
5px     22px    5px
=== =========== ===
```

What I want css to do:

DIV

```
5px                  280px                       5px
=== ============================================ ===
```

Note: The 280px are only the region of 22px repeated along x in the image above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change the layout of your sprite to something like the following:

```
-----------------------
-Left Part  Right Part-
-     Middle Part     -
-----------------------
```

This way, you would change the `y` co-ordinate for the middle part of the `background-image` and it should repeat succesfully.

This is because you cannot repeat a specific part of a `background-image`. The width/height would have to be fixed in this case, as once you repeat a part, you would see the other parts of the sprite.